# CardLayout to close on last card

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

So I have a JPanel with a CardLayout.
this CardLayout, as expected, manages the switching of panels in the frame.
The switching is done by two buttons: "Back" and "Next".

I want to know if there is a way to close the whole application (i.e. call `System.exit(0)`) when it is on the last *card* and "Next" is pressed again.

I have looked for a solution everywhere, but I can't find anything.

The problem is: I don't know how to check which is the last one.

Here is the listener excerpt of my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        CardLayout l = (CardLayout) holder.getLayout();
        if(arg0.getSource() == opt[1]){ //opt[1] is the "Next" button


                //Insert if statement here to check if
                //the CardLayout is on the last card
                {
                System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    l.next(holder); //holder is the JPanel with the CardLayout
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: In the handler for the "next" button, call exit() (or dispose() on the frame) if the current card is the last one. Not sure where you're having trouble -- it's really that straightforward.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill The problem is: I don't know how to check which is the last one. I see a method .last() but that one lays out the last card and doesn't return anything (to maybe compare it with the one card i consider last).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [`dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) which is inherited from [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)? <strike>Make sure you set:</strike>

```
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

```
JFrame frame = ...

// ...

frame.setVisible(false); // hide the GUI
frame.dispose(); // destroy and release the GUI resources
```

---

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardLayoutGUI
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton btnBack;
    private JButton btnNext;
    private CardLayout cLayout;
    private JPanel panUp;
    private JPanel panDown;

    private static final String[] cards =
    {"card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5"}; 

    private int currentCard = 0;

    public void init()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ((JPanel)frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnNext = new JButton("Next");

        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                btnNext.setText("Next");
                currentCard--;
                cLayout.show(panUp, cards[currentCard]);
                if(currentCard == 0) btnBack.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                btnBack.setVisible(true);
                currentCard++;

                if(currentCard == cards.length - 1) // last card
                {
                    btnNext.setText("Exit");
                    cLayout.show(panUp, cards[currentCard]);
                }
                else if(currentCard >= cards.length)
                {
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    cLayout.show(panUp, cards[currentCard]);
                }
            }
        });


        cLayout = new CardLayout();
        panUp = new JPanel(cLayout);
        panDown = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panUp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panDown, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panDown.add(btnBack);
        panDown.add(btnNext);

        for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) createPanels(panUp, cards[i]);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        btnBack.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void showGUI()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanels(JPanel container, String label)
    {
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        pan.add(new JLabel(label));
        container.add(pan, label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                CardLayoutGUI clg = new CardLayoutGUI();
                clg.init();
                clg.showGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I extended CardLayout to add a few features. One of the features is an `isNextCardAvailable()` method. See [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for all the features.

Comment: Now this is the kind of stuff I wonder why is it not part of the standard API.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is determining which card is the last one. You could use a card `String` array index to manage the current position of the and use the [show](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) method to display the next "card". When you exceed the card array index you can then dispose your `JFrame`.

Comment: Yes, I was using that until I discovered `next(Container parent)`, but then I came over this issue. So I guess I will go back to doing that if there is no other way of checking if it's on the last one.

Comment: `CardLayout` keeps the details of which card its on to itself so you will have to manage the navigation index information. The array approach is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the System.exit(0), that close all aplication, but if you only close the JFrame you can use JFrameObject.dispose().

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I edited the question since it seems you didn't get what I was asking.